# Rewriting the sql query with dataframe; how to mix different sources from select

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, dataframe

I need to rewrite sql query with several joins to python using pandas and dataframes. I have no problem making joins, but it gets complicated when I want to refer to data that is not strictly from join.

SQL to rewrite:

```
SELECT 
    table1.id,
    field1,
    field2,
    count(DISTINCT x.apple, x.grape) AS fruits,
    min(x.time) min_value
FROM table1
    JOIN table2 x using(id)
    LEFT JOIN table3 using(id)
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

My current code:

```
mydf, df2, df3 = ...
mydf.merge(df2, on=['id'], how='inner')
mydf.merge(df3, on['id'], how='left')
mydf = mydf[['id', 'field1', 'field2']] # problem, missing fruits, min_value and id should be table1.id
mydf.groupby('id', 'field1', 'field2')
```

I know how to join them, but I don't know how to then create a dataframe that will contain the required elements from the select like e.g. `table1.id` or `min(x.time) min_value`

Tables

```
Table1 columns: [id, field1, field2, field1_2, field1_3]
Table2 columns: [id, field1, field2, apple, grape, time, field2_1, field2_2]
Table3 columns: [id, field1, field2, field3_1, field3_2]
```

**EDIT**: I added sample tables, corrected the error in line 4 of my code, and added a summary.

Comment: Do you have example data we can test our solutions with?

Comment: While creating dataframe you need to ensure to select relevant columns only. That way joining and resultant will be same as expected. Also in your sample , you have not done group by in Python.

Comment: If you would like to ensure you can get answers here, better provide some sample data (eg. first few rows of the dataframe after the merge).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    mydf = mydf[['id', 'table1', 'table2']]
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and I provided wrong code. Instead of ```mydf = mydf[mydf['id', 'field1', 'field2']]``` I mean ```mydf = mydf[['id', 'field1', 'field2']]```. I have already corrected the mistake in the post.